# Python3 Class method inputs; clean solution

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, methods, types

I'am using more class based programs, however in some cases it's not handy to provide all self.paramets into a class.
In those cases I want to use a regular input into a function in a class. I figured out a way to achieve both inputs, let me show this in following script:

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

  def myfunc(a):
    if (type(a) == str):
        name = a
    else:
        name = a.name
    print("Hello my name is " + name)

p1 = Person("John", 36)
p1.myfunc()
print("---------------------")
Person.myfunc("Harry")
```

Output:

```
Hello my name is John
---------------------
Hello my name is Harry
```

First, the name is initialized by the classes self.params.
Second, the name is provided in the method within the class as a string.
So a type check is necessary.

However I don't think this is a clean approach, because when I have >30 methods I need to implement these type checks again, including upcoming type-error results.

Does anyone know a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to implement a [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?#object.__str__) method for your class.  This method will be called whenever something tries to convert an instance of the class to a string.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

p = Person('Jane', 25)

print('Hello', p)
'Hello Jane'
```